# How to run broker 'HiveMQ' localy and connect android application to it

Tags: java, android, iot, paho, hivemq

I followed a tutorial to send message to the hiveMQ(which run through executing run.bat file that I downloaded from their website) from paho graphical user interface downloaded from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/tool/) , it worked fine and showed logs that client connected and sent message that worked fine, now I have made android client application that can publish messages to the public broker, that also worked fine I successfully published message to their public broker(tcp://broker.hivemq.com:1883)

I want to have hiveMQ as broker on my computer so that I can send messages from my application to locally running broker and see the message what I sent from application, how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you run the default HiveMQ configuration, you can reach the broker via your computer's IP address on port 1883. So if you run the application on the same computer as the HiveMQ: 
Broker Address: `tcp://127.0.0.1:1883`

Otherwise:
 use `ifconfig` (Mac/Linux) or `ipconfig`(Windows) command in terminal to determine your external or internal IP-address

Broker Address: `tcp://'ip-adress':1883`.